# Handle typos in manual navigation to URLs in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, navigation

Looking for a solution to the following problem:

When the user manually navigates to a url, e.g `www.website.com/logi` and makes a typo,
I'd like to have some logic to navigate him to the correct `.../login` url. My website has ~10 pages that have different navigation urls and I want to check for typos there as well. Logic that can check for 1-2 character differences and smartly navigate the user even when they make a typo.

What would be a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the Angular documentation, `UrlMatcher` is something which will best suite for your need.

Link: https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

You may now alter/write a `RegExp` based on your need.

Answer (score 1):

Add a catch-all route after all the other routes. In it, check if you should redirect. If not, show a 404 Not Found Error.

```
// Routing module

const routes = [
  // Other routes first
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

```
// NotFoundComponent

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const redirects: [string, string[]][] = [
        ['logi', ['/login']]
    ];
    for (const redirect of redirects) {
      if (
        new RegExp(redirect[0], 'i').test(
          this.route.snapshot.url[0]?.path || ''
        )
      ) {        
        // If on Universal server, set Response status to 301
        this.router.navigate(redirect[1]);
        return;
      }
    }
    // Show 404 error
    // If on Universal server, set Response status to 404
  }
```